# What is the regex patten for this?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex pattern to find all the content b/w curly brackets. For example, there is a string.

```
$string = {xxx yyy zzz}
```

I want to find a regex pattern so that it can extract the "xxx yyy zzz" out but no {}.

Thank you very much for your help.

---

Thank you for the responses.
I'm using PHP for testing. And here is my test code:

```
$string ='start {first find me} and {second find me}';
preg_match_all("/{([^{][^}]*)}/", $string, $matches);
  foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
    echo $value;echo "<br/>";
}
```

I will have:

```
{first find me} 
{second find me}
```

But I expect:

```
first find me
second find me
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If the `{}` are not nested,

```
\{([^}]*)\}
```

If you're using PCRE and they're nested <sup>[ref](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)</sup>,

```
\{([^{}]++|(?0))*\}
```

Otherwise, make a simple parser.

Comment: To elaborate, you'll need to pull the first group match out using whatever language you're executing the regex in. For example, in javascript it would be: `text.match(/{([^}]*)}/)[1]`.

Comment: I'm testing on PHP. Here is my code.
$string ='start {first fine me} and {second find me}';
 
 preg_match_all("/{([^{][^}]*)}/", $string, $matches);
 
 foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
  echo $value;echo "<br/>";
 }
What I want is this.
first fine me
second find me

But I still get this with the pattern.
{first fine me}
{second find me}

Answer (score 0):

```
/\{(.+)\}/
```

It will be returned in the first capture.

Comment: this has possibly incorrect behavior if the string looks like '{xxx yyy zzz} {aaa bbb}', FWIW. I say "possibly" since the original question doesn't really say if this sort of input is possible or likely, or what the expected output would be in such a case.

Comment: It could be anything inside {}.
I tested the pattern but it still has the {} in the return result.

Comment: stackoverflow munched my backslashes.  grr.

Answer (score 0):

building on what Kenny already had, you have to check for extra stuff at the beggining, and add the global modifier.  I'm not sure about php, but I can do it in javascript

```
var str = "start {first fine me} and {second find me}";
reStr = new RegExp(/[^\{]*\{([^}]*)\}/g);
var result = str.replace(reStr, "$1")
```

result will be "first fine mesecond find me"